# What is the relationship between table dcOverTimeSummary and D2 in this SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a following SQL server stored procedure implemented by a consultant. Give a date range between @EarnedDate_frm and @EarnedDate_to to calculate the Over Time DOLLAR_TOTALS and TIME_TOTALS and compare last year same date period these two data grouped by Reason_desc.

My question is what is the relationship between table dcOverTimeSummary and Alias table D2? Self Join but no Join keyword?

```
SELECT reason_desc,
       DOLLAR_TOTALS = SUM(DOLLAR_TOTALS) OVER (PARTITION BY REASON_CODE, UNF_CIV_IND, Cash_Time_Ind),
       TIME_TOTALS = SUM(TIME_TOTALS) OVER (PARTITION BY REASON_CODE, UNF_CIV_IND, Cash_Time_Ind),
       ISNULL(
       (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT DOLLAR_TOTALS)
        FROM dcOverTimeSummary D2
        WHERE (D2.Earned_Date >= FORMAT(DATEADD("yyyy", -1, @EarnedDate_frm), 'MM-dd-yyyy') AND Earned_Date <= FORMAT(DATEADD("yyyy", -1, @EarnedDate_to), 'MM-dd-yyyy'))
            AND (D2.REASON_CODE = dcOverTimeSummary.REASON_CODE AND D2.UNF_CIV_IND = dcOverTimeSummary.UNF_CIV_IND AND D2.Cash_Time_Ind = dcOverTimeSummary.Cash_Time_Ind)), 0.00) AS prev_DOLLAR_TOTALS,
       ISNULL(
       (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT TIME_TOTALS)
        FROM dcOverTimeSummary D2
        WHERE (D2.Earned_Date >= FORMAT(DATEADD("yyyy", -1, @EarnedDate_frm), 'MM-dd-yyyy') AND Earned_Date <= FORMAT(DATEADD("yyyy", -1, @EarnedDate_to), 'MM-dd-yyyy'))
            AND (D2.REASON_CODE = dcOverTimeSummary.REASON_CODE AND D2.UNF_CIV_IND = dcOverTimeSummary.UNF_CIV_IND AND D2.Cash_Time_Ind = dcOverTimeSummary.Cash_Time_Ind)), 0) AS prev_TIME_TOTALS
FROM dcOverTimeSummary
WHERE (Earned_Date >= @EarnedDate_frm AND Earned_Date <= @EarnedDate_to)
ORDER BY reason_desc;
```

Comment: Please format your code next time so that it's at least marginally legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D2 is a table alias for dcOverTimeSummary in the inner scopes of the subqueries.  It differentiates the use of the table in the subqueries from the use of dcOverTimeSummery in the outer query.  It is not a self join.  Using the D2 alias is required in the subquery to do the comparisons to the values from the outer query scope.

Comment: Thanks, squillman. Will the outer where clause limit the subquery data select?

Comment: It will in the sense that only the records that match the outer WHERE clause conditions will be included in the subqueries as well.

Comment: YES. I am suspicious about the result the stored procedure returned. Outer Where clause will return all records, for exaple, happened from date 09/01/2021 to 09/14/2021 to compare records happened last year 09/01/2020 to 09/14/2020. Two set records supposedly don't match.